# How to convert pandas dataframe to sqlite database

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single database .pd which I want to disaggregate into several tables to form a single sql database .db

I have previously created the empty .db

```
data_path = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\homeworkpython\db.db'

conn = sql.connect(data_path)
cursor = conn.cursor()
```

The mother base is 'df'.

so, `df.head(1)` show

```
coordinates     created_at     extended_entities     geo      id
  None          Sat Dec 14           NaN            None      1
```

I create my first table

```
df1 = df[['created_at ','id']]
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(r'sqlite:///C:\Users\User\Desktop\homeworkpython\db.db')

df1.to_sql('tab1', engine)
```

But i have doubts about whether the table was well created and is inside the .db base, how to know?

Answer (score 0):

#### option 1

read table data into dataframe, you may use these [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)

```
df2 = pd. read_sql('select * from tab1', engine)
print(df2)
```

#### option 2

You can install any sqlite database explorer like one in these [link](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/)

Using these tool, you can explore the database